# Any idea on why this program is returning that 987 is a prime number (when it is not a prime number)?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, primes, function-definition

I think the problem is with the for-loop but I cannot understand it. This is an assignment in school that I only should use for-loops and if statements to solve!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int is_prime(int n){
  for (int i=2;i<n;i++){
    if (n%i!=0){
      return 1;
    }
    else{
      return 0;
    };
  };
}

int main(void){
  printf("%d\n", is_prime(11));  // 11 is a prime.      Should print 1.
  printf("%d\n", is_prime(383)); // 383 is a prime.     Should print 1.
  printf("%d\n", is_prime(987)); // 987 is not a prime. Should print 0.
}
```

Comment: Do you know what does a return statement do?

Comment: Your program is returning `1` when there is **at least one** `i` which isn't a divisor of your number. The number is prime when it has no divisors except `1` and a number itself

Comment: Your program never tests `i` with value `3` because the function returns on the "previous loop".

Comment: Your testing was inadequate so the question was premature. Why not test more than 3 numbers? One of the first things you could have done when you discovered that there was a bug was to do something like test all numbers in the range 2-100 to get some idea about what sort of numbers your code was failing at. That would have shown you that your code *always* returns 1, which might have focused your attention on `return 1`

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the null statement after the if statement and the for loop itself

```
  for (int i=2;i<n;i++){
    if (n%i!=0){
      return 1;
    }
    else{
      return 0;
    };
    ^^^
  };
  ^^^
```

is redundant.

Due to the if statement the for loop is interrupted as soon as either `n % i` is not equal to `0` or is equal to `0`. So in general the behavior of the function does not depend on whether the passed number is prime or not prime.

If you will move the return statement

```
return 1;
```

outside the loop as others advised nevertheless the function will be still incorrect. It will show that `0` and `1` are prime numbers while they are not.

Also the condition of the loop makes the loop inefficient at least because it is clear before entering the loop that any even number except `2` is not a prime number.

Pay attention to that the function parameter should have unsigned integer type.

The function can be defined the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_prime( unsigned long long int n )
{
    int prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;
 
    for ( unsigned long long int i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = n % i != 0;
    }

    return prime;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%d\n", is_prime( 11 ) );
    printf( "%d\n", is_prime( 383 ) );
    printf( "%d\n", is_prime( 987 ) );
  
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
1
0
```

Comment: Nothing in the question leads to “Pay attention to that the function parameter should have unsigned integer type”. It is entirely reasonable to have a prime predicated function that accepts negative numbers and reports they are not prime.

Comment: There is no reason to remark on the null statement first. It is more useful for the first thing in the answer to address the critical flaw in the code, the premature `return`.

Comment: `int prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;` is unnecessarily obtuse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is **`return 1` *inside* the loop**. When you find *one* `i` that is not a factor of `n`, you assume `n` to be prime. But you have to ensure that *all* `i` are not a factor of prime, so the `return 1` must be placed *after* the loop. However, that would cause numbers < 2 to be considered prime, as they do not enter the loop at all. Therefore, you also have to add an additional `if` at the beginning.

By the way: Every divisor of `n` (expect `n` itself) must be <= sqrt(n), therefore you can speed up your function quite a bit.

```
#include <math.h>

int is_prime(int n) {
  if (n < 2)
    return 0;
  int max_divisor = sqrt(n);
  for (int i = 2; i <= max_divisor; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0)
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: It dosen't work either. I would still get 1 for non prime numbers.

Comment: @Future Here is [what I initially suggested](https://onlinegdb.com/Il-Io3l9r), and it works for numbers >= 2. For numbers < 2 there was indeed a bug. I [fixed that](https://onlinegdb.com/K93gsjK06).

Answer (score 0):

Problem: return statement

```
  return 1;
}
else{
  return 0;
```

It causes the loop to exit then and there. In your case too, it exits as soon as the first '1' is achieved.

Solution: Instead you should try to store the values in a variable and compare with '1' or '0' at the end of loop

Comment: Nope. Even if I do like you said, the problem still exists. I will still get 1 even for non prime numbers.